# Ajax php file call fails

Tags: php, ajax

I had this script working, to replace a target element in the DOM with the content of "sample.html" file:

```
$('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
$('#loading').show();
$('#target').load('sample.html', function() {
$('#loading').hide();
});
```

After that, I needed to transform sample.html in sample.php because I must call some functions in it.
The above script doesn't work now, if a simply replace 'sampe.html' with 'sample.php'..

Ajax doesn't call its content anymore

Comment: what is your PHP script?

Comment: Can you use Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/) to determine if there are any JS errors?

Comment: You don't need Firebug just to view Javascript errors. The regular FF javascript console (shift-ctrl-J) will report them for you.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error output do you have? Did you try some breakpoints? How far did execution go? What did the console say about the download of 'sample.html'? What is the difference in content between 'sample.html' and 'sample.php'? Maybe it's failing to serve properly.

Comment: sample.php is a simple html file, with html content and some JS script first. Ajax replaced some text with its content (also text). I replaced it as php file because I had to call the function session_start at its top and a conditional statement after (inside a JS script). No errors or alerts in console executing the Ajax call and this just stops. At the end, sample.php text rendering goes well if I open it in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried visiting the 'sample.php' page individually? Perhaps you have a syntax error or something more sinister like PHP is not working/installed on your server.

Comment: Thx Stephen but I tried and the file renders correctly, no errors.     Php is installed in the server and everything other is ok